# How to pass content in to different template parts in Wordpress (split screen)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created a split screen template which I want to use across various pages. I want the content to be different on both sides in all of these templates. For instance on my 'about us' there will be a nav menu on the left and content on the right. But on my 'services' there will be content on the left and right of the split screen.

So how can I change the content which will be added in that space according to which page I am on? I will be using ACF if that makes any difference.

How do I pass in different content to each side of these template parts? Or is there another way?

I was considering adding the split screen for each page, but that isn't very DRY. My split screen template HTML is below:

```
<section id="content">
    <section class="left-split">
        <div class="left-split-content">

            // left side content here

        </div><!-- left split content -->
    </section><!-- left split -->

    <section class="right-split" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="70">
        <div class="right-split-content clearfix">

            // right side content here

        </div><!-- content -->
    </section><!-- right split content -->

</section><!-- content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP can use $_GET to transfer data in web link from page to page

for example, we want to transfer "fruit" = "apple"
http://www.example.com?fruit=apple

```
<?php
$fruit = $_GET['fruit']; // value is "apple"
```

**More info please refer to below links:**
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with similar scenario where I'd to get city page (Created in wordpress post type as page) with respect to the slug name generated by the category.

In your scenario,You've to create a custom template where you've to check whether the page is service page or a about us page. After that create two pages in wordpress with services and about us page and insert all the content in the description. Now when you do this,get the page content by slug name you generated (can be found [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Get_a_post_by_its_slug/)) by using conditional statement. If you're using shortcodes inside your content you can use `<?php do_shortcode('[PASTE YOUR PAGE CONTENT HERE]'); ?>` and you'll get everything.